# Looking for an example on how to use the Initial File List function

Tags: fine-uploader

I have looked over the doc and searched for forums but I can not seem to find an examples on how to implement the Initial File List functionality for fine-uploader.

Below is the script that I am using - works great but what I would like to do is to use the Initial File List function to populate the fineuploader with the existing files that have been uploaded during this session.

I have code that will return a json feed with the required files in an array format.
I just can ot figure out where our how to call the function to initalize.

Thanks in advance.

```
 <script>
// Wait until the DOM is 'ready'
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'upload.cfm'
            },
    session : {
           endpoint: 'imageStatus.cfm',
           refreshOnRequest:true
            },
     validation: {
            itemLimit: 2,
            allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg", "gif" , "png"],
            sizeLimit: 5000000 // 5 MiB
            },
    messages: {
        tooManyItemsError: 'You can only add 2 images'
            },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true, // defaults to false
            endpoint: 'upload_delete.cfm?uuid=',
            method: 'post'
            },
        retry: {
           enableAuto: false
            },
         scaling: {
            sendOriginal: true,
            hideScaled: true,
            sizes: [
                {name: "THUMB_XX", maxSize: 113},
                {name: "FULLIMAGE", maxSize: 450}
                ]
            },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html -- Are you having problems with this not working? If it is not working, it is most likely an issue on your server. Please post any console messages if so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fineuploader - initial file list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493305/fineuploader-initial-file-list)

Comment: I have read the doc at docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html  I am trying to get an example on how to implement the calls.  Just confused on what to do

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue.
ends up that I did a custom build of the JS files and did not include the status function.
rebuild the downloads and works like a charm.
thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the right one, please do that! It'll help others who would be searching for the same thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The initial file list feature is not a function that you call, per say, it is an option that you set in the client. More or less, all you need to set is the endpoint where the uploader can retrieve this list of files, and then have your server correctly process them.

The server response should be a JSON Array of Objects.

`[{ name: 'foo.jpg', uuid: "7afs-sdf8-sdaf-7asdf" }, ... ]`

The trickiest part is getting that list of files server-side, and you may want to ask some Coldfusion folks about how to do that.

Comment: I have that code done - that was the easy part
    [
{
"id": 0,
"name": "image 1",
"uuid": "0b6ec63b-ab06-4926-bed0-03a9f478eab2",
"thumbnailUrl": "http://memsaic.com/app/2_250/767_03192014/pics/0b6ec63b-ab06-4926-bed0-03a9f478eab2.png",
"status": "upload successful"
}
]

but I do not see the call being made.

Comment: I have confirmed that the session endpoint is working and valid JSON data is coming back.  I have also placed debugging on the page to tell me that the page is getting called.  Issue is the page is NEVER getting called.  

How do you add it to the client?
I currenlty have this code
 'code'$(document).ready(function () {
       var imageuploader =  $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
   session: {
            endpoint: 'imageStatus.cfm',
      params : {transaction_id : <cfoutput>#client.transaction_id#</cfoutput>}
        },

Comment: You do not need to specify an id or status.  Please have another look at the docs, where this is all described in detail.  If the call isn't being made, then you must be using a custom build with the session module excluded, or an old version that did not yet include this feature.